# What is the word that de­scribes the hu­man fe­male breast’s shape?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

*Phal­lic* is fairly com­mon. *Yonic*, *vul­vic*, or *labial* were sug­gested as an­to­nyms.

What is the word to de­scribe the breast’s shape?

We cover up three ar­eas: the male groin, the fe­male groin, and the fe­male chest. Why are there spe­cial words for the first two but not the last one?

Comment: Why should every word have an identical set of word forms or equivalents? There's nothing wrong with *a breast-shaped dome*.

Comment: Don’t you really mean to ask why it is that you don’t know them? :) This is hard for us to answer. I’ve edited your question to be a *what* question not a *why* question to make it more answerable.

Comment: Is a breast not *mammary*?

Comment: @AndrewLeach I would need more convincing that it's more than the specific milk parts: platypus and other monotremes have mammary glands but not breasts.  A mammogram images the internal structures but the removal is a mastectomy not "mammectomy"

Comment: @AndrewLeach I think penile is to phallic as vaginal is to yonic and mammary is to the word we're looking for. It refers to the function or the specifics of the organ more than the shape or some more metaphorical quality. Though I admit the distinction is hazy.

Comment: For instance, penile growth is a growth on (or of) one's penis. A phallic growth is a growth similar in nature or shape to that of a penis.

Comment: @JasonBassford [Fancy that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breast-shaped_hill)!

Comment: There is no word for the female breast shape because there is no such thing as *the* female breast shape. Entire scientific careers have been spent on trying to categorize them. That one German guy counted 28. Not variations, top-level categories. Which category exactly are you looking to name? Because he does have a dedicated term for every single one.

Comment: The (transliterated) Greek word for _breast_ is _mastos_, but the only common English word that incorporates that word as a description of a shape is _mastodon_, the genus of prehistoric elephant named for the shape of their teeth. You can see an example of a [fossil mastodon tooth here](https://www.cnn.com/2014/04/18/us/michigan-mastodon-tooth/index.html). According to _The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language_, fifth edition (2010), one meaning of _mastoid_ is "Shaped like a breast or nipple," but the word isn't widely used in this sense in everyday English, as far as I know.

Comment: @SvenYargs If it’s Greek you want, while *mas­tos* (*μαστός*) is just a sin­gle teat, *stethos* (*στῆθος*) is the en­tire bo­som in full. There’s also *bathukolpian, bathy­colpian* < *βαθύκολπος*, both of which al­ready ex­ist—but per­haps you might set­tle for *cal­lis­tet­hous* for the Bac­trian ver­sion or *cal­li­mas­tian* for the dromedary. Speak­ing of which, Latin and her chil­dren have sup­plied English with a huge whole lot of words about this that no­body has men­tioned yet, like *mam­mate, mam­meated, mamel­onated.* *Tec­tonic* is quite nice once you strike its spu­ri­ous let­ter.:)

Comment: @RegDwigнt: Not to forget that the shape of a breast changes considerably depending on the relative direction to gravity.

Comment: *Why are there spe­cial words for the first two but not the last one?* because dudes can have *boobs* too, which is what breasts are shaped like.

Comment: @RegDwigнt True, but the same is true of the penis (and every other part of the human body) as well, yet _phallic_ is a common-enough word.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet every penis is shaped like a penis. Every foot looks like a foot. Every head looks like a head. Every single one of them. But not every boob is a tit. That's why we have different words for them. They are not the same shape at all. Any word you can think of that covers all breasts ever will refer to function, not form. Nature, not shape.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I don’t see the difference at all. Every breast is shaped like a breast just like every penis is shaped like a penis; there is huge variation in both.

Comment: @tchrist Your "If it's Greek you want" comment is screaming to be made into an actual answer.

Comment: Those antonyms are a no-go. phallic is not always about shape....You guys need to get a life. To heck with science. Try buying a bra. HERE: https://www.thirdlove.com/pages/breast-shape-dictionary :)

Answer (score 24):

**Mammillar** and **Mamillary** are (apparently) used to refer to things that are breast or nipple shaped (but are not breasts or nipples).

The [non-OED Oxford dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mamillary) (for mammillary):

> Shaped like or resembling a breast or nipple

The [free dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/mammillar) (for mammillar):

> (Biology) resembling a breast or nipple

Answer (score 18):

The term you're looking for is *breast-shaped*.

Examples:

> Winter Park may buy **breast-shaped** building on Lee Road ([*Orlando Sentinel*](https://www.orlandosentinel.com/news/breaking-news/os-breast-shaped-building-winter-park-sale-20141202-story.html), 2014)

> During the colonial and early American periods, the mountain was known as "Mamelle" mountain. "Mamelle" is a name commonly applied in the French-speaking parts of the world to a breast or any **breast-shaped** hill. ([*Encyclopedia of Arkansas History & Culture*](http://www.encyclopediaofarkansas.net/encyclopedia/entry-detail.aspx?entryID=1248), 2016)

> Is the **breast-shaped** shadow on St. Mary’s Cathedral an accident or a clever prank? ([*KALW*](https://www.kalw.org/post/breast-shaped-shadow-st-mary-s-cathedral-accident-or-clever-prank), 2018)

Comment: But many mountains that have breast-related names are not shaped remotely like any breast I've ever enountered.  For a prime example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Teton  Whoever named that had been a LONG time without female companionship :-)

Answer (score 9):

> **mammiform**  in British (ˈmæmɪˌfɔːm)
>
> adjective **having the shape of a breast**
>
> Collins English Dictionary.
>
> https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/mammiform

Comment: most people with a verbal IQ of 125 will not have heard that word before ;-)

Comment: @barlop Most of those same people will, however, be able to work out what it means by its components.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  Sure, I didn't say they wouldn't know what it meant, I only said they won't have heard it before. Once they hear it they'll know what it means, and then they may look it up to check that the word really exists!

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest "mammillary", since it appears in the phrase "[mammillary body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mammillary_body)", the usual term for a brain region named for its breast-like shape.

Answer (score 2):

The trigonometric "sine" function derives its name from the Latin "sinus" meaning "bosom". This is itself a translation of the Arabic word "jaib" (also meaning "bosom"). The use of "jaib" is said to be due to phonetic similarity with the original Sanskrit "jiva" for "chord" transliterated into Arabic as "jiba" or "jb", but this would surely have been reinforced by the breast-like shape of this function.

So, if the sine function is breast-shaped, surely we can say the breast is sine-shaped?

Comment: That would certainly be translinguistically circumlocutory. But you are right, why not? :)

Answer (score 1):

[Mammaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mammary) is the plural to describe the breasts as it comes from 17th Century English (from mamma + -ary)

Mammary glands are glands within the breast which hold milk when lactating, and although the word mammary is [used in the medical profession to describe breast tissue in both men and women](http://mentalfloss.com/article/61894/can-men-lactate), hense the word *mammogram* for male breast cancer testing ([see here](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/breast-cancer-in-men/diagnosis/)), the word is only used in the generalised sense when talking of female breasts.

> *ADJECTIVE*
>
> Denoting or relating to the human female breasts or the milk-secreting organs of other mammals.
> *"mammary tumour viruses"*.
>
> *NOUN*
>
> *informal*
>   A breast.
> *"Page Three has become synonymous with mammaries"*.
>
> **Pronunciation**
>   **mammary** /ˈmaməri/

Answer (score 1):

Websters and Oxford dictionaries both define ***mound*** as  "A rounded mass projecting from a surface". I would suggest that it is simple, unpretentious,and easily identified as a descriptor of "breast-shaped".

Answer (score 1):

Following tchrist's comment, if it’s Greek you want, while

> mas­tos (μαστός) is just a sin­gle teat

and the source for mastectomy,

> stethos (στῆθος)

is the en­tire bo­som in full (source for stethoscope). There’s also

> bathukolpian, bathy­colpian < βαθύκολπος,

both of which al­ready ex­ist — but per­haps you might set­tle for

> cal­lis­tet­hous

for the Bac­trian ver­sion (patterned after 'callipygian') or

> cal­li­mas­tian

for the dromedary. Speak­ing of which, Latin and her chil­dren have sup­plied English with a huge whole lot of words about this that no­body has men­tioned yet, like

> mam­mate, mam­meated, mamel­onated (for teeth protuberances), mammatous (for clouds).

Or

> Tec­tonic

is quite nice once you strike its spu­ri­ous let­ter. Guess which one!

For the record, none of these are really used for the way that you presumably intend, but they surely should (spellcheck barfs over all these suggestions except for 'tectonic')